# Update div (with AJAX) only if form input has no value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of results that are shown on a particular page and these are updated at regular intervals using a simple AJAX request. An input form allows me to filter these results, but as the data is updated every few seconds, the input form doesn't work properly as it refreshes all the data. Is there any way for the AJAX to not update when there is a value in the form input field?

Below is the HTML code:

```
<div id="my-query-results" class="visible">
  <div>
    <form class="searchboxInput" action="#">
      <input id="kwd-my-query-results" type="text" value="">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="my_recent_queries">
    <span class="loading_placeholder">Loading ...</span><br />
    <img src="../img/ajax-loader.gif" />
  </div>
</div> <!-- my query results -->
```

Below is the AJAX request that I was using:

```
if( $("#kwd-my-query-results").val() != "") {
  function updateMyQueries() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/myrecentqueries",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $("#my_recent_queries").html(html);
      }
    });
    setTimeout("updateMyQueries()", 600000);
  }
  updateMyQueries();
} else {
  function updateMyQueries() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/myrecentqueries",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $("#my_recent_queries").html(html);
      }
    });
    setTimeout("updateMyQueries()", 4000);
  }
  updateMyQueries();
}
```

The above if else statement just didn't seem to work. It would evaluate to the else statement once a value was present in the input box. I think I also tried length(), but that didn't seem to work either. Any other way of approaching this?

**Update**

I tried the following given the suggestion below, and it works to some degree. It loads the results initially, allows me to search them without reloading the data, but then it doesn't reload the results at regular intervals, even when there is no text in the input field...

```
$(function(){
  setTimeout(updateMyQueries(), 4000);
});

function updateMyQueries(){
  if ($("#kwd-my-query-results").val() == "") {
    // do ajax call
    $.ajax({
      url: "/myrecentqueries",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $("#my_recent_queries").html(html);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have amended to use setInterval instead of setTimeOut. Can you try again? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by moving the updateMyQueries function out of the if statement then maybe something like this.

```
$(function(){
     SetInterval(updateMyQueries(), 4000):
})

function updateMyQueries(){
    if($("#kwd-my-query-results").Val() == ""){
          // do ajax call
    }
}
```

EDIT - this will work

```
setInterval(function (){    
    if($("#search").val() == ""){
           // Ajax call here
        }
    }, 4000);
```

​

Comment: This worked! Thanks very much. I had to add another AJAX call at the beginning so that it would also load on document load, not just for the first time after 4 seconds, but this helped me massively.